# Select records in next 30 minutes

Tags: mysql

I have the following structure in my `queue` MySQL table:

```
id | post_id | datetime_requested
```

I have a record in my table.

```
1 | 1234 | 2021-10-01 11:20:00
```

I want to run a **SQL Query** every 30 minutes to grab any records in the *next* 30 minutes.

So if the script ran at 11:00:00 it should grab the above record.

The below correctly gets the record:

`SELECT * FROM queue WHERE datetime_requested >= ('2021-10-01 11:00' + interval 30 minute);`

but this also works too, when it shouldn't:

`SELECT * FROM queue WHERE datetime_requested >= ('2021-10-01 10:00' + interval 30 minute);`

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query return records with a `datetime_requested` after `10:30`. This is why you get rows for `11:30` as it meets your criteria.

Maybe try with `BETWEEN`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM queue
WHERE datetime_requested BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```